# Cannot load some modes via elpa

Tags: package, package-repositories

[image]Some of my major modes, installed via ELPA, error during load as, for instance for markdown-mode,

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "../../../../.emacs.d/elpa/markdown-mode-20210405.1...")
  markdown-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(markdown-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
```

. I've tried understanding why the load-path is relative and doesn't work. But without any clues. Need help.

**Update**:

After having set `debug-on-message` I've found some more clues.

The error is trigger by the expression

(with-demoted-errors "File mode specification error: %s"
(set-auto-mode))

in the function `normal-mode` when I open a D (.d) file.

Prior to the call to `with-demoted-errors` the `load-path` looks ok and does not contain any relative paths. I'm attaching a screen from the EDebug session.

Several other elpa packages such as magit are affected. I don't see any common property of those failing packages.

The `let` of the variable `enable-local-variables` sounds suspicious...

Comment: What is the value stored in your `load-path` variable? Do you change the value of `load-path` somewhere in your config?

Comment: I've studied the value `'load-path`, yes. Nothing unusual. So it must be changed temporarily somehow. Can one set a hook that runs when a variable changes?

Comment: I this question needs more information to get a proper answer. I don't think, there is a hook for changing a var, but you could advice `setq` and `setf` to do so. If that helps is unclear, due to `load-path` being a special variable and so its value can temoprarily be modified by `let`.

Comment: I'm gonna try `(setq debug-on-message "No such file or directory\" \"../../../../.emacs.d/elpa")`.

Comment: I've gained some more insight into the problem. See above.

Comment: Show us the code used in your init file - if installed with elpa/melpa, the full package name ```emacs.d/elpa/markdown-mode-20210405.1...``` should not be there, it is enough to write ```(use-package markdown-mode)``` or ```(require 'markdown-mode)```.

Comment: I've always used the package name as argument to use-package, in this case `(use-package markdown-mode)`. I believe something is temporarily and intermittently changing the `load-path`. It affects other packages aswell, such as `electric-operator` and `magit`.

Comment: Note that the docstring of `normal-mode` explains why `enable-local-variables` is bound that way.

Comment: Your screenshot of file `files.el.gz` looks pretty standard, it is unlikely the error is there. If it happens (only?), when you load a `.d` file, then maybe the problem is in `d-mode` or your config of that package. I would also take a look at `electric-spacing-mode`.

Comment: The problem goes away when I explicitly load all the .elc files in `electric-spacing-mode` and reopen the .d file. But then the same error is triggered by other packages that are bound to autoloading when I open a .d file. Can it be a problem with autoload paths?